# Failed to resolve: support-v4 in android studio

Tags: android, support-v4

I got this error after I update to android studio 3.1.3

```
Failed to resolve: support-v4
```

after try to build project in android studio.

Here is my `build/gradle`

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.8.1'
}
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'http://clinker.47deg.com/nexus/content/groups/public' }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "app.udrinkidive.feed2us.com.customerbeta"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 20
    versionName "THONGLOR-RC19-20180509-C"
    multiDexEnabled true
    manifestPlaceholders = [
    onesignal_app_id: '13976026-a6ff-42e2-8f58-744a1692aa42',
    onesignal_google_project_number: '665136907244'
    ]
    javaCompileOptions {
        annotationProcessorOptions {
            includeCompileClasspath = true
        }
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        debuggable false
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.6.0, 3.99.99]'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.7.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.2.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.2.1'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.1.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    implementation 'com.github.elevenetc:badgeview:v1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.cocosw:bottomsheet:1.+@aar'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:percent:26.0.0'
    implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.4.0'
    implementation 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.+'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.10.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
    implementation 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0'
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
}
```

How to check out what's really going on? I can't find it neither on stackoverflow nor google.

As you can see I tried to add `implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'` in `dependencies` still doesn't work.

How to solve it?
Any part in the project I should take a look?

Comment: test case `implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0'`

Comment: Never use wildcards in your dependencies. It's unpredictable what version it'll use. Your app might break one day and you won't know why. Check this page for the latest version https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages

Comment: @NileshRathod same error sir

Comment: @ZUNJAE I am not sure what you mean. What is "wildcards"?

Comment: @SarinSuriyakoon try this `repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }`

Comment: you use a `+`, which means it will get the latest version automatically. This may cause dependency conflicts.

Comment: Just delete line `implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'`... That library is pulled in from the others you have

Comment: I think you'll get a different error, too... `firebase-core:10.0.1'` need to have 11.6.0 to match the other Google GCM libraries

Comment: @SarinSuriyakoon I 'm facing a similar problem with a gradle that was working normally some days ago. what did you do? I've facing the same. I've already deleted .gradle folder and is still failing

Answer (score -1):

Delete `caches` folder inside `~/.gradle` folder and sync again. It worked for me.